# Embed Python Zip file throws error?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I am trying to embed the python zip file in my application.
I downloaded the zip file from the python site, (the win32 one).

This is the code I use to set the python path

```
#include <Python.h>
...
std::wstring exe_dir = L"\\exe\\path";
std::wstring python_path;
python_path += exe_dir + L"python-3.5.1-embed-win32.zip";
Py_SetPath(python_path.c_str());

Py_Initialize(); // Error : "Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec"

...
```

But no matter what I do, the app throw the same error all the time.
Even if I play around with various path.

How can I embed the zip file in my app?

Answer (score 1):

There is another zip file inside *"python-3.5.1-embed-win32.zip"*.

```
python35.zip
```

And that file is the one that needs to be added.

```
#include <Python.h>
...    
std::wstring exe_dir = L"\\exe\\path";
std::wstring python_path;
python_path += exe_dir + L"python35.zip";
Py_SetPath(python_path.c_str());

Py_Initialize();    
...
```

I would be interested to know what the other files are for, (or if this is the correct way to use it) ...

Comment: I created a [blog post](http://www.myoddweb.com/2016/02/27/embed-python-in-your-c-application-without-python-installed-on-guest-machine/) with links to python and steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last question about "what the other files are used for" in the embedded distribution, you'll see errors on certain imports.  I got an error importing `NumPy` / `SciPy` because one of those files outside `Python35.zip` was missing - `_ctypes.pyd`.  Also figured out the small file `pyvenv.cfg`has to sit next to your EXE at least on Python 3.5.2, which is just a text file that says `applocal = true`.  Of course you need `python35.dll` of course...